# Is it a good idea to create a clustered index on a Foreign Key?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I have a Login Table that has a Identity field "Id" as the Primary Key(clustered) , and other fields like email , password etc.The only time I will use this table is to authenticate the user.After that i will be always querying other tables like user_profile, user_comments etc which has a foreign key Login_id to the Login Table.
My question is, is it a good idea to make the Login_id in the user_profile and user_comments table , a clustered index ? I will not be doing any join with the Login table since after the user is successfully authenticated, i will keep the LoginId in FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie for future querying the child tables.

I am developing a web app using C# and .Net.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you will never use the index, there's no point in creating it.  Adding it will just increase the time it takes to do inserts.

Comment: Sorry i was mentioning i will not use the login table after authentication, and not the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will be constantly using the Login_id to get data from  user_profile and user_comments, and assuming these searching using login_id in those tables will be more often than any other columns like Id, in those tables, then "login_id" should be  clustered indexed . Basically, you would want to use the clustered index on column that gets queried the most. It could be two columns like "first name" and last name. From MSDN

> It is important to define the clustered index key with as few columns
>   as possible. If a large clustered index key is defined, any
>   nonclustered indexes that are defined on the same table will be
>   significantly larger because the nonclustered index entries contain
>   the clustering key. The Index Tuning Wizard does not return an error
>   when saving an SQL script to a disk with insufficient available space.

Comment: Thanks ! Then i will set the login_id as clustered index on user_profile table.There is a search feature too where users can search for a user using their first or last names from user_profile table. So i guess i could create a secondary index on name fields ? Thanks !